# MySQL Master-Master Replication

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following query in MySQL:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication'@’10.141.2.%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘slave’;
```

It keeps returning the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??10.141.2.%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘slave’' at line 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "fancy quotes" (see how they 'lean') ? Replace `’` with `'`

`'replication'@’10.141.2.%’` should be `'replication'@'10.141.2.%'`

(also, it appears you are doing it on `IDENTIFIED BY ‘slave’;` as well)

Comment: Thanks. I miss that completely.

Comment: @user1527556 glad it was an easy fix

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I've carefully typed ' on keyboard, still getting the same error.